# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent not working in godaddy server

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, godaddy-api

I developed a website in local using Laravel 5.2. All functions are working perfectly. But when I have uploaded it in godaddy server, all functions are working except eloquent. Insert, Update, Delete all works. but in database engine it is showing MYISAM. I change it in INNODB. But still eloquent are not working. Is it the problem of foreign_key constrains?? Error is eloquent variables are not getting data. How to fix it??

Error:

```
<body>
    <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
        <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
        <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix">
            <span class="exception_counter">1/1</span>
            <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException">FatalErrorException</abbr> in <a title="/home/abhaymilestogo/public_html/floorstyler/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php line 797" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 797</a>:</span>
            <span class="exception_message">Class &#039;\App\Model\organization&#039; not found</span>
        </h2>
        <div class="block">
            <ol class="traces list_exception">
                <li> in <a title="/home/abhaymilestogo/public_html/floorstyler/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php line 797" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 797</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

agency.blade.php

```
<tr>
    <th>{{$agency['id']}}</th>
    <th>{{$agency['name']}}</th>
    <th>{{$agency->organization->name}}</th>
    <th>{{$agency['status']}}</th>
    <th>{{$agency['updated_at']}}</th>
    <th>{{$agency['created_at']}}</th>
    <th>
        <a style="font-size: medium;" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" href="agency/edit/{{$agency['name']}}/{{Crypt::encrypt($agency['id'])}}"></a>

        <a style="font-size: medium;" class="fa fa-trash-o" id="{{Crypt::encrypt($agency['id'])}}"></a>
        @if($agency['status'] == 'ALIVE')
            <a style="font-size: medium;" class="fa fa-times" id="{{Crypt::encrypt($agency['id'])}}"></a>
        @else
            <a style="font-size: medium;" class="fa fa-check" id="{{Crypt::encrypt($agency['id'])}}"></a>
        @endif

    </th>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

the problem is in {{$agency->organization->name}}

Comment: Is there error showing? Did you check the error log? Did you setup the database correctly?

Comment: Yes. I think database set up is correct. but not sure about foreign key as the table initialized with MYISAM engine. Later I have change it to INNODB.
Error:
ErrorException in eeb31122066c28d05a0d3e03d88967b5c2d171dd.php line 51: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/abhaymilestogo/public_html/floorstyler/resources/views/agency.blade.php)
This error occured only for one variable which contain the eloquent function. If I remove it then error is not showing.

Comment: Show your `agency` and `organization` model in your question.

Comment: Did you import the local db, or does your database has some data?

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly states that Class \App\Model\organization not found.

Please check if you have defined the namespace in the Model class 'organization' and verify that the path you are specifying is correct.

Moreover, it is a good practice to always name your classes with the first letter capitalized.

If this does not solve the error, kindly post the file agency.blade.php.

Comment: yeah it is absolutely correct and it is working in my local machine. I am uploading agency.blade.php code. where the problem is.